# PHP + JavaScript PopUp Windows

Tags: php, javascript, sql, popup, window

On my page, the following function has been created:

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function popModData( modName )
    {
        var url = "./modList.php?mod=" + modName;
        newWindow = window.open( url, modName, 'width=500,height=500,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,toolbar=no,directories=no,location=no,menubar=no,status=no,left=0,top=0');
        if( window.focus ) { newWindow.focus() }
        return false;
    }
</SCRIPT>
```

And, the page itself is **modList.php** which loads data of different game-mods from SQL table. I want each of the game-mod name clickable, so that a pop-up opens. I am using this in the php page generation:

```
while( $modTable = mysql_fetch_array( $getMod ) )
{
    $colour = ( $i % 2 )? "#99EECC" : "CCDDFF";
    echo "\t\t\t<tr bgcolor='$colour'>";
    echo "\n\t\t\t\t<td>" . $i++ . ".</td>";
    echo "\n\t\t\t\t<td onclick='return popModData($modTable[Name]);'>$modTable[Name]</td>";
    echo "\n\t\t\t\t<td>$modTable[From]</td>\n\t\t\t</tr>";
}
```

Upto this, no trouble is faced. Now, the trouble is pop-up window opens for the first entry in the table, but not for any of the other 516 values.

I thought of having another file to process the mod name( for eg. modData.php ) but, the problem is still there.

Please help. If anything is missing there, please mention, and I will try to put it up too!

Comment: Can you post the generated HTML?

Comment: ^ this. And: where do you initialize the $i counter? How's the sql query?

Comment: @damien $i is initiated just above while loop as $offset+1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surround the names with " " as you need javascript to parse them as strings.

Like this:

```
while( $modTable = mysql_fetch_array( $getMod ) )
{
    $colour = ( $i % 2 )? "#99EECC" : "CCDDFF";
    echo "\t\t\t<tr bgcolor='$colour'>";
    echo "\n\t\t\t\t<td>" . $i++ . ".</td>";
    echo "\n\t\t\t\t<td onclick='return popModData(\"$modTable[Name]\");'>$modTable[Name]</td>";
    echo "\n\t\t\t\t<td>$modTable[From]</td>\n\t\t\t</tr>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Dunno why it worked now. I tried putting it like `return popModData('$modTable[Name]');` and `return popModData(\'$modTable[Name]\');` too.

Comment: You are already inside an onclick='...' dont use ' inside ' as it makes no difference in js if you use ' or ", so you can always use he other. Also php possibly ate the \ anyway.